# Annotate an entity with @Transient

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, persistence

I have a class annotated with @Entity hence stored in database. Now what I want to do is to extend it, but the child class shouldn't be persisted at all:

```
@Entity(name = "A")
public abstract class A {

    private String field;

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public abstract void print();
}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(getField());
    }
}
```

Why can't I annotate B with @Transient to prevent creating additional unnecessary entries in database? Do I maybe miss something important?

Comment: @Transient is a JAX-B annotation used to control which fields get turned to/from XML and has nothing to do with JPA which is why it has no effect.

Comment: @Pace `@Transient` is a JPA annotation (it is also in the package persistence) and is used for fields that are not persistent: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html

Comment: You are correct.  I had that completely backwards in my head.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid that instances of `B` get persisted, you do not need to annotate it with `@Transient` (which is used for marking fields/properties that are not persistent), but rather avoid annotating it with `@Entity` or simply do not list is in your persistence.xml file.

Besides you must make sure that your code will never try to persist such a type, otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: just for clarification: if I then instantiate B and persist the data, won't it be stored in database (I'm using Hibernate if it does make any difference)?

Comment: No, it won't be persisted, because you didn't annotate it with @Entity. But if your code will try to persist it (somehow), an exception will be thrown.